# error while launching the php server for zend application

Tags: php, zend-framework2, windows-8.1

I downloaded zend skeleton app from [here](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication). Then I installed it by executing the following commands.

```
cd Desktop/zendprojects
git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git
cd ZendSkeletonApplication
composer self-update
composer install
```

Then I decided to launch it locally, so I executed this command:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php
```

And I got this error:

```
Directory public/ does not exist.
```

I checked project structure and `public` directory exists in the file structure. How can I fix it?

Comment: as you can see, you specified `public` directory as the base, therefore it'll look for another `public` dir within public which doesn't exist. `php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/` should be enough.

Comment: I got same error; i.e., `Directory public/ does not exist. `

Comment: sorry, It appears to be working in both cases which makes my assumption false :(. But now I noticed that you are in windows, therefore you might need to use backslashes `\\` . php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public\ public\index.php

Comment: No luck with backslashes. Same error

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public public/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

try it without "-t": php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 public\ public\index.php

Answer (score -1):

if you are on windows try this in the folder where you have the app installed:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:80 -t .\public public/index.php
```